# Error in import statement for accessing beanfactory

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, installation, javabeans

I am trying to implement a basic spring example my import statements are
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
"The type org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext is not accessible" getting this error in both the lines.

Tried adding correct source, all the JAR files but it is not working.
I am adding JAR files from build path>>add external jar.
Looks like I am missing some step but not able to decode.
Anyone faced similar issue please help.

Comment: Show us the project's Java Build Path property page's Libraries tab.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Maven or Gradle instead of manually importing the JARs.

If, for some reason, this isn't an option, then check clean your project and check if you've added all of the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Include below dependency and build the project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.9</version>
</dependency>
```